# C++ Передача списка va_list в функцию

Tags: c++

Подскажите, как реализовать функцию:

```
int test(...){ printf(...);}
```

То есть передать параметры va_list в следующую функцию.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Просто так передать неопределённый список аргументов невозможно, в языке нет синтаксиса для этого. Однако проблему можно обойти, как указано [здесь](http://c-faq.com/varargs/handoff.html): функция, *которой* вы передаёте управление, должна иметь вариант, принимающий [`va_list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/variadic/va_list).

Для вашего случая, вы можете использовать [`vprintf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/vfprintf):

```
void test(char *format, ...) // должен быть хотя бы один аргумент
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);
    vprintf(format, args);
    va_end(args);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Или макросом:

```
 #define prn(A,...) printf(A,__VA_ARGS__)
```

иногда так проще, особенно если надо добавить к **VA_ARGS** дополнительные аргументы.Но по уму все же по изучать VA_* [интерфейс](https://linux.die.net/man/3/va_arg).